# How to fix Class 'Behat\Behat\Output\Printer\ConsoleOutputPrinter' not found

Tags: php, plugins, phpstorm, behat

Im trying to use the Behat plugin for PHPStorm (on Behat 3). the problem is once i try to run a feature i will receiving the following Fatal error:

```
Fatal error:  Class 'Behat\Behat\Output\Printer\ConsoleOutputPrinter' not found in /private/var/folders/js/27x3tw5n5jx9b14vn_cn12w0748zmg/T/ide-behat.php on line 82
```

I had a look in the Behat source i can see there is no such file, and instead we have "Behat\Behat\Output\Printer\ConsoleOutputFactory"

I did try to manually change the code in "ide-behat.php" but as sson as you run the test the file will be regenerated automatically

Any advise will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears in Behat 3.0.x-dev the output printer is under changes and ConsoleOutputPrinter gives its place to ConsoleOutputFactory.

So for the time being i solved my problem by switching to Behat 3.0.15 specifically.

e.g. by changing dependency in composer.json from

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "3.0.x-dev"
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "3.0.15"
    }
}
```

But still it will be interesting to learn more about ide-behat.php file and understand amend it, to be ready for the upcoming changes in new Behat.

Comment: Unfortunately the PHPStorm plugin is not yet compatible with Behat3.

Comment: Well, its not compatible with the Behat3's development branch, it seems the latest stable version (3.0.15 at the moment) works fine. but for sure its time to the plugin to be updated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the "Behat" folder in the same folder of the file.

and try it once.

Let me know if the issue still occurs

Comment: 1. Which file? ide-behat.php? or my feature file?

Comment: 2. By Behat folder you mean the one in the src? i.e. ...//vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat

Comment: May be your file(ide-behat.php) location and "ConsoleOutputPrinter" file location is different. And the file "ide-behat.php" is trying to access "ConsoleOutputPrinter" from the location where you have put the "ide-behat.php" file. Just check for the file locations.

Comment: I see your point. but the issue is in the latest Behat-3 dev branch the file is not exist anymore, so its not a matter of routing but the file is missing :) thanks for the respond